# Resetting an Event Animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a template for an off-canvas navigation that fades in each item in a list sequentially.

I've set it so the off canvas menu disappears when:

1. the bg is clicked
2. the 'X' is clicked

My problem is in how I've structured the animation reset.  If, for example, you activate the menu, close it quickly, and activate it again, you'll catch the animation as it fades out and fades back in again.

What I'm trying to accomplish is if the used selects one of the methods to close the menu then there is basically a hard re-set of the code but I don't know how to execute a mid-state reset.

Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var square = $('.square');
 
 square.click(function() {
  $('.ocn').addClass('showOcn');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('.ocn li').each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(100 * i).fadeIn(500);
  });
 }, 1000);
  

  
 });
  
 
 
 $(document).on('click', '.ocn', function() {
  if( $('.ocn').hasClass('showOcn')) {
   $('.ocn').removeClass('showOcn');  
   
   $('.ocn li').each(function(i) {
   $(this).fadeOut();
  });
   
  };
 });
 
});
```

```css
.page {
 height: 500px;
 width: 900px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.square {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

.ocn {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

ul > li {
 color: white;
 display: none;
}

.showOcn {
 z-index: 2;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page">
 <div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div class="ocn">
 <ul class="myNav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Three</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) and [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but finish, in this context, will just force the animation to conclude, but not reset the parameters? I.e. it will finish the fading of the list items but not reset the fadeIn animation?

Comment: Yes..correct. ...

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question?

Comment: Sure...just do it

Comment: The menu style I'm trying to recreate is like this one: http://threadslike.com one thing this menu does well is it almost prevents the user from being able to click while the menu resets. Any idea how that is being done? Just point me in a direction

Comment: Can use `:animated` selector and if some element `is(':animated')` don't run the rest of the code  http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you put your answer as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: No worries..not sure what to answer. Happy to help someone from TO...grew up there many moons ago

Answer (score 0):

Is this popup menu what you need?

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/#Menu